# Calling __init__.py from another file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to understand how __init__py works. But I have the following question.

I have the following directory:

```
myfoldername/
   example/
      __init__.py
      sayhello.py
      saybye.py
   main.py
```

Inside the __init__py file I import the sayhello.py and saybye.py files

```
from example.sayhello import *
from example.saybye import *
```

Inside the sayhello.py I have two functions:

```
def hello():
    print('hello')

def hello_person(x):
    print('hello ' + x)
```

Why can I not call the both functions in the sayhello.py when I import the module into a separate script main.py?

```
import example as ex

ex.hello() //prints 'hello'

ex.hello_person('John')  //prints module 'example' has no attribute 'hello_person'
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you've saved your `sayhello.py` file as is? Because you shouldn't get this error unless the file _really_ doesn't contain the function `hello_person()`.

Comment: Hey @mfonism, so I think something is being very strange, even though I save each file individually,I get errors when i run the main.py file.  But when i restarted my IDE it is working now.  I also restarted once more, and now my main.py can't identify my example subfolder.....

Answer (score 0):

Though that shouldn't have happened. but if the issue is still there you can make use of [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). Which says

> Explicit is better than implicit.

Hence,

```
from example.sayhello import hello, hello_person
```